# how to send a struct instance using prepare for segue

Tags: swift, struct, segue

Let's say I have

```
struct cat {
var paws: int
var name: string
var breed: string
```

}

How would i go about segueing an instance to a new destination controller?  Particularly, this instance from an array to a new DC?

```
prepare for segue

{
if segue.identifier == "segue"
var nextVC = segue.desitnationviewcontroller as ...
nextvc.instance = ?
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign it like this:

```
let someCat = cat(paws: 4, name: "Kitty", breed: "Unknown")
let arrayCat = [cat(paws: 5, name: "Mutant", breed: "Unknown"),
                cat(paws: 4, name: "John", breed: "Doe")]

var nextVC = segue.desitnationviewcontroller as SomeViewController
nextVC.somePropertyName = someCat // or arrayCat if you're using an array
```

In your `SomeViewController`, you'll have to have a property with type `cat` and you can just assign it. For example:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var somePropertyName: cat? // [cat]() if it's an array of type cat
}
```

Also, for your convenience I added a link to Apple's documentation of Swift. The link is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/).

Comment: Now, let me ask this.  Say I have 2 cat instances in the array "let catarray = [somecat, someothercat].  how would i then go about segueing this info?

Comment: by changing type of the property "somePropertyName" to array of cats which is [cat]. I encourage you to read the book "The Swift Programming Language".

Comment: Like mehmet6parmak said. I updated the answer. Please mark it as answered if it answered your question :)

Comment: thank you for the addition, but two questions.  For one, shouldn't arrayCat include someCat? and then with that, shouldn't nextVC.somePropertyName = arrayCat?

Comment: No problem. You can include someCat in arrayCat. I just used two separate examples. How you create the array is up to you. As for question 2: It should be arrayCat, as I've put in my answer. It's just commented out in `// or arrayCat if you're using an array`. To sum it up, you're correct with these two questions as it's basically the same as what I've answered in the answer ;)